# How do I reach $rootScope from a component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am very new to AngularJS/Ionic/Cordova programming and am trying to handle the visibility of a component using a global variable, so it can be hidden or shown from other components. I am creating the variable when calling the `run` function, assigning it to `$rootScope`.

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        // Some Ionic/Cordova stuff...

        // My global variable.
        $rootScope.visible = true;
    });
})
```

My component is:

```
function MyComponentController($rootScope, $scope) {
    var self = this;
    self.visible = $rootScope.visible;
    alert(self.visible);
}

angular.module('myapp')
    .component('myComponent', {
        templateUrl: 'my-component.template.html',
        controller: MyComponentController
    });
```

And the template:

```
<div ng-if="$ctrl.visible">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

However the alert message always shows "undefined". What am I missing?

Comment: 1st place you shouldn't be think of using `$rootScope`, create a service and share its variable wherever you need..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$rootScope.visible` isn't watched when being assigned as `self.visible = $rootScope.visible`. And it is `undefined` at the moment when component controller is instantiated.

It can be

```
function MyComponentController($rootScope, $scope) {
    var self = this;

    $scope.$watch(function () { return $rootScope.visible }, function (val) { 
        self.visible = val;
    });
}
```

By the way, it is likely available as `$scope.$parent.visible` and can be bound in template as `ng-if="$parent.visible"`, but this is antipattern that is strongly discouraged.

There may be better approaches:

- top-level `AppController` and `<my-component ng-if="visible">`, so the component doesn't have to control its own visibility
- broadcasting it with scope events, `$rootScope.$broadcast('visibility:myComponent')`
- using a service as event bus (that's where RxJS may be helpful)
- using a router to control the visibility of views, possibly with route/state resolver (this is the best way)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations, I'll check them.

Answer (score 0):

How about change `self` to `$scope` like this:

```
function MyComponentController($rootScope, $scope) {
    $scope.visible = $rootScope.visible;
    alert($scope.visible);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `$rootScope.visible == undefined`. It doesn't matter if it's assigned to  `$scope.visible` or `self.visible`.